# Where should i store uploaded files in server?

Tags: php

i am learning php as well as doing a project that involves uploading files to the server. My goal is to make it as secure as possible so where do you recommend saving all the uploaded files. The files to be uploaded will all be pdf files. I read somewhere it's better to save uploaded files outside document root and in some other place i read it's not easy to access files outside document root from php so i am very confused. Any help towards best practice to overcome this situation is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: this is a disccusion question. It does not fit with this site. It is your decision and its up to you.

Comment: The danger of uploading to the document root is basically about what would happen if the person doing the uploaded gave you a PHP/CGI script, and the went to that URL.  The person would be making your system run their code.  There is also the danger that they could upload javascript or something else, that could be used for evil elsewhere on your site to attack your clients.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the reason for not storing files in a root path is in theory someone could guess the director, and access the files, you could either learn permissions (on the server) which may prove to be very difficult, or you use something such as NAS drive (which will appear as if it is a local drive to your network but no one outside of the network can see) however this can be expensive and is another thing you would need to learn (configuring the NAS box). If those two do not work, try either using a separate drive on the server or partitioning the drive into two drives. and storing files there, as for the code its self, just specify the full path and treat it as you would any other file on a root drive (that is how I have done it but I am not PHP pro). If you have any other questions feel free to ask, I hope I answered this one for you :)

Here are a few ways to partition drives:

Vista/Windows server 2008(or most other windows servers): http://blogs.technet.com/b/steve_lamb/archive/2008/07/08/how-to-re-partition-a-hard-disk-under-vista-or-server-2008-without-having-to-re-install.aspx

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

For security purposes, it's not a bad idea to store uploads temporarily outside of the document root until they're screened for executable code or to make sure they are what you're expecting. This way anyone who gains access to the upload mechanism can't upload a backdoor through your interface and then access it via a browser (and take over your server). Also they couldn't upload malicious code that causes your site to do something else.

Once that screening has taken place, in order for someone to access the files (view the PDFs), the files ultimately need to be stored above the document root for good SEO. That way they can be linked to and mined for info by search engines without taxing the server.

Some people say you could store them below the document root and then present them to the users as an attachment that you stream to them with fread. The problem is if you're using files that are large, you may run your particular server instance out of resources if there are several people or bots connected at once.

You could also store them directly streamed in the database, but this provides no additional security whatsoever outside of the initial screening. Also it takes memory and overhead to actually retrieve them from the database, and again the search engines might run your system out of resources if they all connect at once.